# how to prevent image move outside margin of a div

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when I move an image.
When the browser resizes the image moves outside the class `col-md-6`.

This is my CSS and html:

```css
#gradiente2 {
  background: rgba(43, 86, 162, 1.00);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

#img5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 3%;
  left: 434px;
  bottom: 74px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" id="gradiente2">

  <p id="t1" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "En nuestra institución siempre nos preocupamos por brindarte lo mejor"  ]'><span class="wrap"></span> </p>
  <p id="t2" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Síempre le Ponemos Corazón, a lo que hacemos" ]'><span class="wrap"></span> </p>

  <div id="movimiento">
    <img src="imagenes/kangura.png" class="img-responsive" id="img4">
    <img src="imagenes/corazon.png" class="img-responsive" id="img5">
    <button class="animar">Entregar Corazón</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: I see you haven't accept any answers given to your questions. If you expect users to spend the own spare time helping you, you need to start doing that.

Comment: Also, post a _working_ code snippet using the built-in Stack snippets.

Comment: sorry for that i am learning english so far to do this, but for now on, i accept all answers, thank you for telling me that.

Comment: how do i do that just post all my code?

Comment: Not all, but  just the ones that deserve it: when answerers are giving you correct answers or when they are making efforts helping you.

Comment: Here is how to use Stack snippets: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) for rearranging the CSS according to your requirement.

in this question, you have to change the value of

```
#img5{  
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 74px;
 }
```

Comment: i use margin-top and left with %, that helps too, thanks.